# change style on hover for element

Tags: jquery

The element class `walkingRoute-container` is between a link tag, and I wonder how to do, to highlight an element with a color that stays when a click is made on the element and removed when a click is made on another element, but not when hover? I would also like to change the `<p>` inside the element to another color when hover?

Appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Code is as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".walkingRoute-container").hover(
function(){
   $(this).css("background","#02baff");
},
function() {
  $(this).css("background","#c1c1c1");
})
```

});

Comment: isn't that working? I think you should add a bit of your html code and also (if possible) `try on ` http://jsfiddle.net and what is this `orther` element?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery function `css` also takes parameter like json object.

```
var obj = {
    'height': 100,
    'width': 100,
    'background', 'red'
    };

$(element).css(obj);
```